# Unbalanced Longitudinal Multilevel Model Power Analysis

Tags: r, mixed-model, panel-data, multilevel-analysis, statistical-power

I am trying to conduct a power analysis on a multilevel longitudinal model (pre-existing household panel dataset) and am having trouble figuring out how to do it (or if it is even needed in the first place, however I am assuming that I will be asked the question by reviewers if I do not include it). I am using R for all analysis (lme4 package) and would therefore prefer an R solution if possible (but it doesn’t have to be).

Below is a summary of the model.

Outcome DV

- Job satisfaction measured over time (up to 10 time points)

Level 1 (within-person) variables:

- Time
- Personality trait 1
- Personality trait 2
- Personality trait 3
- Personality trait 4
- Personality trait 5
- Employment status (part-time or full-time, coded as 0 or 1)
- Monthly gross income

Level 2 (between-person) variables:

- Time (the between-person component of the level 1 variable)
- Personality trait 1 (the between-person component of the level 1
  variable)
- Personality trait 2 (the between-person component of the
  level 1 variable)
- Personality trait 3 (the between-person component
  of the level 1 variable)
- Personality trait 4 (the between-person
  component of the level 1 variable)
- Personality trait 5 (the between-person component of the level 1 variable)
- Employment status (the between-person component of the level 1 variable)
- Monthly gross income (the between-person component of the level 1 variable)
- Gender
- Average age

Cross-level interaction:

- Time (level 1) x Personality Trait 1 (level 2)

The model has job satisfaction as its outcome variable where I am interested in modelling the growth in job satisfaction as a consequence of between-person (level 2) extraversion (hence the cross-level interaction). Individuals serve as the level two clusters (N = 7,275) and observations of time serve as the primary level one predictor (N = 23,974, unbalanced such that different individuals have different N observations). All other variables are covariates and for all time-varying covariates I have split them into their within-person and between-person components (hence the double-up at level 1 and level 2 for all variables but age and gender).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Power analysis for an existing dataset does not really tell you much. It basically gives you the same conclusion as the p-value if you analyze the data. For more discussion on this, check this [post](http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2014/12/observed-power-and-what-to-do-if-your.html).
- If you still want to do it, then given the complexity in your design I would say that the only viable approach is simulation. That is, you simulate, say $B = 1000$ datasets from your model based on the postulated design, you fit the model in each dataset and you perform the test of interest and keep the p-values. The proportion of times the p-value was significant at a give level will be your power.

Comment: I agree with your first point but was not aware of that post - very helpful, thank you! That said, I would still like to know how to conduct such a test for my model (or future models). Any links/references to assist with this would be appreciated (the post you linked doesn't seem to cover MLMs).

Comment: You mean a link/reference on how to simulate from a mixed model?

Comment: Yes, so basically I would like to know how to implement in your second point (although, I appreciate that this specific question may be better suited to Stack Overflow).

Comment: Check this post for a piece of code that will need to be suitably adapted though: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/376570/random-group-by-time-interaction/376647#376647